# How to get a security certificate from the server and install in the device certificate list like in Browser

Tags: android, certificate, installation

I need to implement an SSL connection similar to a browser implementation, I need to show a dialog if the certificate is not from a trusted source and accept the certificate and proceed with the connection.  please guide me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement a custom [X509TrustManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/javax/net/ssl/X509TrustManager.html) that verifies the server certificate based on the standard trusted root certificates from Android and additionally an own trusted list.
See `checkServerTrusted(..)` method.

If an invalid/untrusted certificate appears you can ask the user if it should be added to your own trusted list.

Comment: How to add the certificate to the list, should i create a .bks file ?

Comment: You have to implement the certificate validation on your own, therefore it is your choice how to do it. You can of course use an KBS file stored in the application data path.

Comment: u mean to say create a keystore.BKS file ?

Answer (score 0):

You can only install trusted certificates on Android 4.0 and later. You can catch the certificate error and then ask the user to install the certificate using the [KeyChain API](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/security/KeyChain.html). It requires user confirmation, so you cannot do this automatically.

Comment: i'm developing application for Android 2.2 , please guide me on how to add certificate to device cetificate list.

Comment: You need to create your own key store file and certificates as needed. See here form some explanation and sample code: http://nelenkov.blogspot.com/2011/12/using-custom-certificate-trust-store-on.html